# Docker for Windows unresponsive after restarting VM

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, docker, docker-for-windows

I've installed Docker for Windows on my Windows 10 machine, which uses Hyper-V. The default VM that gets installed is the MobyLinuxVM. To change some settings, I shut down and restarted the VM. But after that, Docker wasn't working anymore.

In Powershell:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker info
Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine
```

In the log:

```
[13:18:03.963][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> GET /_ping
[13:18:03.963][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket SOME-GUID
[13:18:03.969][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket SOME-GUID
[13:18:03.973][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] error reading response from Docker:  HvSocket has already been closed
[13:18:03.973][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] proxy >> GET /v1.26/info
[13:18:03.973][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Dial Hyper-V socket SOME-GUID
[13:18:03.974][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] Successfully dialed Hyper-V socket SOME-GUID
[13:18:03.975][ApiProxy       ][Info   ] error reading response from Docker:  HvSocket has already been closed
```

What is happening here? Why can't I restart the VM?

A restart of my *machine* fixed it, but shouldn't I be able to restart the VM? It wasn't caused by the changed settings, because I could reproduce it by just restarting without changing any settings.

Comment: I tested 2 fixes at the same time, and it solved this problem for me:
- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/971#issuecomment-321559479
- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/711#issuecomment-300989118